# performance/load testing tools to test rest api(headless rest endpoint) without GUI

Tags: csv, tfs, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

Please help me in finding performance /load testing tool to test a non GUI endpoint. Also tools that allow tests to be exported in csv or xml format and are compatible with source control like GitHub and or tfs. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run simple, automated tests and test e.g. an API I would recommend using Locust - http://locust.io - if you like Python, or Gatling - http://gatling.io - if you're OK with scripting in Scala. These two are modern, well documented tools with a nice DX (developer experience). Jmeter is a bit old-fashioned, not so easy to get started with or to use and has a ton of features you're not likely to need.

Other options are:

- wrk - https://github.com/wg/wrk - very simple and high-performing tool, scriptable in Lua
- the Grinder - http://grinder.sourceforge.net/ - scriptable in Java or Python (Jython)

And if you want to use an online (SaaS) tool there are of course us (loadimpact.com), Loader.io and Blazemeter.com to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Gatling tutorial, it has all the basics needed to quickly start performance testing with Gatling: [Performance testing with Gatling](http://automationrhapsody.com/performance-testing-with-gatling/)

Answer (score 0):

TFS provides web performance load tests out of the box.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/load-testing.aspx

Comment: are there any other tools that are compatible with non GUI based rest api. I cannot record my api because it does not have a User Interface

Comment: The web performance tests don't require a UI.  The "recording" is just a list of HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/) or [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), both satisfy your requirements.

Reference material:

- [Using SoapUI for load testing](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/load-testing.html)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)